# How to edit this query to select data instead of update

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How do i edit this query to select data from user table instead of update.
i want to use the first condition to select data from the second table.

the code runs as it is. i just want to modify it so i can perform a select instead of update

```
<?
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $flash = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bazze2", $username, $password);
    $flash->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /* Queries Start */
    $proff1s = $flash->query("SELECT topay FROM merge WHERE torecieve = {$_SESSION['id']}");
    foreach($proff1s as $proff1) {
        $proff2 = $flash->query("UPDATE user SET confirm = 0, tomerge = 'GH', recomit2 = 1, investement = investment2, clearedbalance = topay2  WHERE id = {$proff1['topay']} AND recomit2 = 0");
    }
    /* Queries End */

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to modify this query ""UPDATE user SET confirm = 0, tomerge = 'GH', recomit2 = 1, investement = investment2, clearedbalance = topay2  WHERE id = {$proff1['topay']} AND recomit2 = 0" into a SELECT QUERY ?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Alright so based on the current update query, the equivalent in a select form is something like this :

```
SELECT confirm, tomerge, recomit2, investement, clearedbalance 
FROM user 
WHERE id = {$proff1['topay']} AND recomit2 = 0
```

Some explanation :

- I keep all the field updated in the update query : confirm, tomerge, recomit2, investement, clearedbalance
- The table previously updated is `user` so its where the information is stored FROM
- The WHERE clause remains the same

Hope it's what you want.

Comment: The issue is i am trying to use the query to select the value of the confirm column and display one of two buttons based on the value in the confirm column

Comment: But when i use the query the first button is what shows no matter the value of confirm.

Comment: If you only need the value of the confirm column try this : SELECT confirm
FROM user 
WHERE id = {$proff1['topay']} AND recomit2 = 0

Comment: And print the value of column field